# Nginx rewrite with conditional destination

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a site with two RESTful URL schemes:

`foo.com/model/id` and
`foo.com/model/id/action`

The actual pages served by these URLs are in the form of

`$model.php?id=$id` and 
`$model_$action.php?id=$id` respectively.

I have a single regular expression that will match both cases `^(\w+)s/([A-z0-9]+)(?:/(\w+))?/?$` and I'd like to use a single Nginx rule to rewrite for both types of URLs, but I'm not sure how to do this. In pseudocode I imagine the rule would look something like this

`rewrite ^(\w+)s/([A-z0-9]+)(?:/(\w+))?/?$ /(($3) ? $1_$3.php?$id=$2 : $1.php?$id=2)`

This isn't valid syntax (so far as I know), but can something like this be done in Nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the possible urls in turn starting with the longest to the shortest to that overlapping matching strings, "/model/id" in this case, would be matched in the longer url string first.

```
location / {
    # For "/model/id/action" to "$model_$action.php?id=$id"
    rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)(/?)$ $1_$3.php?id=$2 last;

    # For "/model/id" to "$model.php?id=$id"
    rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+)(/?)$ $1.php?id=$2 last;
}
location ~ .+\.php$ {
    # Handle PHP
}
```

The "(/?)" is just in case the urls sometimes come with an ending slash. If they never do, it can be removed. In this case, it will probably be best to specifically always add a closing slash and have "(/?)" as "/".

Comment: By your answer can I assume that you're saying there's no way to do this with a single rewrite? I'm currently using two rewrites, just as you've outlined, but was hoping to do this with only one.

Comment: Why would I want to? For kicks, curiosity. If I could do it in one line (and it be readable) why do it in two? Unfortunately this doesn't look to be possible. Thanks though!

Comment: Ha! For kicks!! You could probably do it with lua but it'll be a long line :) All in all not worth the trouble.